# Using Request Body in Azure Data Factory

Tags: rest, azure-data-factory

I have a working GET request in Postman where the body contains the query as seen below

[image]

The body is as follows

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "Vrvirksomhed.cvrNummer": "12345678"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Now i'm trying to get the same GET to work in Aure Data Factory but somehow it seems that the syntax needs to be different as it' doesn't use it correctly. Does it need to be wrapped somehow ?

[image]

Comment: What error do you get? I’m guessing based upon the postman docs that choosing “raw” means it sets the HTTP header Content-Type=application/json so you might try that

Answer (score 1):

This is because the ADF will ignore the Request body when your Request method is GET. So it can't work.

You can click '{}' button to view the code of Copy activity.

[image]

Even if your request body has content, there isn't requestBody property in source.
[image]

If you change your request method to POST, it will show.

[image]

So you can change your request method to POST to have a try.