# DataFactory with Web Source - How to use requestBody?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps

We created a LogicApp that pulls data from our Azure AD upon being triggered through a HTTP request. If we call the LogicApp from a Web component, and add a parameter with a value in the Body property, the logic app will pick things up properly.

Web component:

[image: Web component]

Logic App parsing the parameter into the output:

[image: Output gets parsed]

However, when we attempt to do the same from a Copy Data component and using the LogicApp as a source, the Logic App seems to not pick up the parameter. I attempted to use the Request body the same way as the Web's body (but even when hard-coding the value, it doesn't seem to be picked up by the Logic App):

[image: Data Source]

This time the output does **not** get recognized/parsed:

[image: No outputs]

I saw this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67805445/using-request-body-in-azure-data-factory), but that is using a GET rather than a POST method. Where am I going wrong with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And of course within 30 minutes after posting, I figured it out. I tried recreating this example in Postman, and when using the RAW format for Body, it initially did not result in a success.

However, I noticed it defaulted to "Text". Changing that to "Json" resulted in a successful parsing within the Logic App.

Checking the headers sent in PostMan then revealed the Content-Type header used the format = "application/json".

Setting that within the Data Source resulted in a success:

[image]