# Azure data factory web task altering body causing web call to fail

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am placing a web task call to an api.
The body is simple

["val-01-001"]

(note, this works with either single or double qoutes)

If i use this exact value for the body in postman, it works.
If i use this exact value in the body of the web call, the web call tells me *"The posted data is not valid. Perhaps it is not well-formed or match with the samples.Please verify."*

I dont have access to the api code or backend so i cant see exactly what its receiving.

Any idea what Data factory might be doing to the body causing it to be rejected?

I added a Content-Type header with a value of application/json, but this didnt help.

Below are the input and out from the web call and the same call in postman, which works:

[image: Web call input]

Web Call input

[image: web call output]

Web call output

[image: exact same call in postman]

Exact same call in postman

Comment: Did you remember to set the content-type in ADF? I had that issue a while ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72731738/datafactory-with-web-source-how-to-use-requestbody

Comment: Hi, I tried this, adding Content-Type application/json but same result.